# Creating anchor link with punctuation and ampersand

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to create an anchor link in markdown, and the heading I want to link to has both a punctuation mark and an ampersand. I cannot get the anchor link to work.

The heading I want to link to is as follows:

```
## Selected Essays, Features & Reviews
```

And I have tried both of the following without success:

```
[Essays, Features & Reviews](#selected-essays-features-&-reviews)

[Essays, Features & Reviews](#selected-essays-features-reviews)
```

I understand that the punctuation should be removed so I've ignored the comma, but it still isn't working so I assume I'm doing something wrong with the ampersand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anchor links require the anchor - the URL to link to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Github all entities (including ampersand) in anchors will be removed from between the dashes so your link will look like:

```
[Essays, Features & Reviews](#selected-essays-features--reviews)
```

You can inspect Github generated anchors in your browser by pointing mouse at small chain link icon that appears next to headings when you hover over them.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following for example:

```
## [&apos;Selected&apos; Essays, Features &amp; Reviews](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger/blob/master/KUBERNETES.md)
```

gives:

### ['Selected ' Essays, Features & Reviews](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger/blob/master/KUBERNETES.md)